# w3wp.exe process terminates without any line number or clue in error message in .NET MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, model-view-controller

Process got terminated without any logs or line number. And it occurs randomly.
Unable to get any clue. Using MVC5

> Application: w3wp.exe Framework Version: v4.0.30319 Description: The
> process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info:
> System.NullReferenceException    at
> System.Web.SessionState.SessionStateItemCollection.get_Item(Int32)
> at
> System.Web.Util.AspCompatApplicationStep.AnyStaObjectsInSessionState(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState)
> at
> System.Web.HttpApplicationFactory.FireSessionOnEnd(System.Web.SessionState.HttpSessionState,
> System.Object, System.EventArgs)    at
> System.Web.SessionState.SessionOnEndTargetWorkItem.RaiseOnEndCallback()
> at
> System.Web.Util.WorkItem.CallCallbackWithAssert(System.Web.Util.WorkItemCallback)
> at
> System.Web.Util.WorkItem.OnQueueUserWorkItemCompletion(System.Object)
> at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext,
> System.Threading.ContextCallback, System.Object, Boolean)    at
> System.Threading.QueueUserWorkItemCallback.System.Threading.IThreadPoolWorkItem.ExecuteWorkItem()
> at System.Threading.ThreadPoolWorkQueue.Dispatch()

Comment: https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetWebStack/issues/139

Comment: There is no clear answer based on these message, I suggest you use dump to find your problem. [Debug Diagnostic Tool](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=58210).

Comment: @samwu we have tried with dumps as well. but could not reach to the root cause. and dumps affects on application speed as well.

Comment: Analyzing dumps is a very complicated process, I suggest you use [https://support.microsoft.com/](https://support.microsoft.com/).